# Cordova inAppBrowser causes application crash, added angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have created a cordova project and I want to use the inAppBrowser. I have added the plugin like this from CLI `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser` and I have added angularjs to my project. I have cleaned the project in eclipse and also built from CLI.

My applicable html:

```
<input type="submit" value="FB test button" ng-click="loginFaceBook()"/>
```

My applicable code in controller:

```
$scope.loginFaceBook = function() {

    toastr.warning("Button pressed");

    loginService.loginProviders().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        //window.open(data[0].Url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
        var facebook = window.open(encodeURI('www.google.com'), '_blank', 'location=yes');
        facebook.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { console.log('start: ' + event.url); });
        facebook.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { console.log('stop: ' + event.url); });
        facebook.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { console.log('error: ' + event.message); });
        facebook.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { console.log(event.type); });

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // If list of providers are not returned
        toastr.error("Failure");
    });
};
```

The code gets fired and I get the following alert in my app:

`Application Error   There was a network error (file:///android_asset/www/www.google.com)`

I am using cordova 3.4.0

Thank you in advance and let me know if you need additional information.

**EDIT** replaced alert with console.log, still getting the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
encodeURI('http://www.google.com')
```

instead of

```
encodeURI('www.google.com')
```

Comment: Ended up being a different problem. The cordova.js file was not added to the index file. That ended up breaking a couple of other things. I will add another question for that if I cant solve.

Comment: Did you add this line in your index file correctly `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` ?

Comment: I did yes, now it works. The problem now is that when the browser is opened, this is added to the front of the URL - file:///

Comment: If my answer solved your current problem please accept it as answer.

Comment: remove the function `encodeURI`, use only `window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');` @Lunchbox

Comment: Thank you, that sorted the problem out. Arrived at the same conclusion, +1 @AtanuCSE